# Printing an array of strings to a column in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an array of strings that I am trying to print to a column.

I have a loop that reads in multiple excel files and prints their contents to one master excel file, but I want to also print the first three letters of each file name (which is an identifier) to a new column [column H (7)]. Here is my code:

```
for f in files:
    wb2 = load_workbook(f)
    ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']
    for row in ws2.rows[1:]:
        ws.append((cell.value for cell in row))
        #ws.cell(row=row,column=7).value = str(f[:3])
        #ws.append((str(f[:3]) for cell in row)) - prints contents on next row
        a = [str(f[:3])]
        print (a)
```

When I print a, the array has the correct information, but I can't figure out how to append or print an array to my data.

I have tried using different format variations. Some return errors about not being able to convert strings in excel. I have also tried to print the strings directly without assigning them to an array, as seen in the first commented out portion, but it returns the error: unorderable types: tuple() < int(). The second commented out line appends the data to the next row instead of just the next cell in the column. I am sure there is an easy change I can make in my code to fix it, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at using the `offset` method of the last cell in each row to create a new cell next to it.

Comment: I assume you mean column_offset? I can't seem to find much documentation on that aside from the iter_rows function.

Comment: No, cells have an `offset` method.

Comment: Searching online, I've found you mention the offset method many times, but I can't seem to find an example on how to use it. When I try to use cell.offset it tells me that 'method' object has no attribute 'offset'. When I try to use ws.cell.offset it says 'function' object has no attribute 'offset'.